# how to connect to devices using flutter bluetooth?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

So, I'm trying to connect to a device and send some data, using flutter plugings (flutter_scan_bluetooth:to scan for devices) and flutter_bluetooth_serial (to connect and send data) 
I can scan for devices and retrieve their mac addresses but I can't connect , I'm trying to use this function to connect :

```
void connect(String address) async {
try {
  connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);
  print('Connected to the device');
  _isConnected="is connected";

  connection.input.listen((Uint8List data) {
    //Data entry point
    print(ascii.decode(data));
   });

 } catch (exception) {
   print('Cannot connect, exception occured');
   _isConnected="not connected";
 }
}
```

but the app stop and recieve the not connected message (It shows the devices that It found with scan )
what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: in your catch what is the output of `print(exception);` ? also did you add the permissions to the manifest?

Comment: a question: what is address?